# Combine single unique variable in otherwise identical rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm pulling data from an API tracking time spent on projects with variables that include time, client, project, and--potentially--multiple tags describing the project. When I pull the data however, entries with multiple tags are duplicated into otherwise identical rows with a single unique tag per row, like this:

```
 duration client project    tag
       60      A       X  first
       45      B       Y second
       45      B       Y  third
       30      C       Z fourth
```

How would I remove the duplicate rows while combining the tags? I'm thinking either like this:

```
A)
  duration client project    tags
1       60      A       X   first
2       45      B       Y  second, third
3       30      C       Z  fourth
```

or this:

```
B)
  duration client project    tag1   tag2
1       60      A       X   first     NA
2       45      B       Y  second  third
3       30      C       Z  fourth     NA
```

I would also appreciate advice on which suggested arrangement (A or B) would be best for being able to quickly summarise the amount of time spent on projects with, for example, tags "first" and "third" (e.g. 105 mins)?

Here's the example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  duration = c(60, 45, 45, 30),
  client = c("A", "B", "B", "C"),
  project = c("X", "Y", "Y", "Z"),
  tag = c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
  )
```

I appreciate any suggestions (I feel like this shouldn't be too hard with dplyr/tidyr, but haven't quite been able to get it right). Thanks!

Comment: How should the duration data be handled?

Comment: Everything except the tags is an exact duplicate between rows and should be replaced/removed, e.g. 45 min duration for client B/project X, NOT 90 mins. Does that answer your question, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: If the number of tags is limited, you can reshape df to get tags as column names `require(tidyr)  spread(df, key = tag, value = project) `

Comment: Different advice: make two tables `projDF = unique(df[c("client", "project", "duration")]); tagDF = df[c("project", "tag")]` or whatever the appropriate selection of columns is. (Then you'd use `left_join` or similar to combine the tables for any analysis.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` for your output A. `group_by_at(vars(-tag))` is a way to specify that grouping variables should be all columns except `tag` since you want all the other columns are exact duplicate in rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-tag)) %>%
  summarise(tags = toString(tag)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   duration client project          tags
#      <dbl> <fctr>  <fctr>         <chr>
# 1       30      C       Z        fourth
# 2       45      B       Y second, third
# 3       60      A       X         first
```

We can then use `splitstackshape` for your output B

```
library(splitstackshape)
df3 <- df2 %>% cSplit(splitCols = "tags")
df3
#    duration client project tags_1 tags_2
# 1:       30      C       Z fourth     NA
# 2:       45      B       Y second  third
# 3:       60      A       X  first     NA
```

Comment: You could stay in the tidyverse to make the output B with: `df2 %>% separate(tags,c("tags1","tags2" ))` but then you would have to specify the tags column names specifically, or have an extra step to count them first.

Comment: @Johnpaul Thanks for your comments. I thought about using `separate` or `extract` from the `tidyr` package, but then I realized that the number of tags in each row could be different, so `cSplit` is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks @www, that's just the sort of elegant solution I was hoping for. Also thanks @Johnpaul for the tidyverse solution for output B--I don't think I'll ever have >5 tags, so I could use your `separate` line and just ignore the warnings of "too few values at XX locations" that results

Answer (score 0):

Your solution A looks fine to me. I would do it like this:-

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df <- df[, tags := paste0(tag, collapse = ", "), by = project]
df[, tag := NULL]
df <- unique(df)
```

It'll give you the result which you wanted in A approach:

```
duration client project   tags
1:  60      A       X     first
2:  45      B       Y     second, third
3:  30      C       Z     fourth
```

Comment: Thanks! This also does the trick, but similar to my comment to ge.org's solution, I'd really prefer to not have to use an additional package (and associated unfamiliar syntax) for this step, as I've used dplyr/tidyr for the rest of the manipulation. Any way this can be done with dplyr/tidyr instead?

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(project, client, duration) %>%
  summarise(tags = paste0(tag, collapse = ", "))`

Comment: @JMDR, the above piece of code would do the trick using `dplyr`. It'll give the same output as A.

Comment: Fyi, you don't always have to use `:=` in data.table, you could just do `df[, .(tags = paste0(tag, collapse = ", ")), by = project]` or add all the relevant cols to `by=` if really needed.

Comment: @Frank I wanted to add tags column in existing `data.table`. That's why I used `:=`. I know I could have achieved this using `df[, .(tags = paste0(tag, collapse = ", ")), by = c("project", "client", "duration")]`. But, what is wrong with always using `:=` in `data.table`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, just letting you know there are other ways. In this case, one might argue that it's better my way since the original data is left alone and can be looked at afterwards to confirm the code is working, while yours overwrites it. That's partly just stylistic preference, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use plyr for A)

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df, .(client), function(df){
  tags<- paste(df$tag, collapse=",")
  df$tag <- tags
  df[1,]
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick, but I would _really_ prefer not to use plyr as it conflicts so much with dplyr which I use a lot. Any way this can be done with dplyr/tidyr instead?